# How do search engines treat query strings?

Tags: php, seo, search-engine

Do search engines treat different `page.php?querystring`'s differently than different pages (e.g. `page1.php` vs `page2.php`)?

I've heard it recommended to have different pages in these cases for SEO purposes..  Any reason behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages with query strings are not as easy to read, and remember. To my knowledge, Google does not treat query strings any differently than urls like `page1.php`.

The whole SEO issue is that it is easier to use and remember urls like

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406236/how-do-search-engines-treat-query-strings`

than

`http://stackoverflow.com/index.php?questions=6406236&name=how-do-search-engines-treat-query-strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Colum is generally right. Another point is that if you have, say a wordpress blog, and you had myblog.com/?p=1 as a url, it would include less keywords in the url than having the full title in the url. Once you open the door of including words in urls, urls without a bunch of amper signs and equals look better.

Search engines highlight/make bold search keywords in the results they return, so that tends to make people put keywords in the url of a page. Then, you have hybrids, like what stack does, that use combination of both, digits and words. Digits make queries faster, pretty urls make people happy.

Answer (score 1):

Google's own "Search Engine Submission Starter Guide" suggests that real words, in simple-to-understand URLs are best.

It's a PDF: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

(See pages 8-11)